# User limitations with software on a VPN

Tags: remote-desktop, vpn

Here is the breakdown of our situation:
2 locations
location 1 has file server(SBS03), 6 workstations, and a VPN(SBS08). 
location 2 has 5 workstations and needs to access a database that is stored on the file server.

Each location has their own local domain and firewalls.

On SBS03 we have a program installed and folder it is installed in is mapped a drive for local users to access. The local users are in the domain but work as standalones with access to mapped drive from SBS03 to install an agent on workstation that allows access to the program and database(it more or less puts a working file on each workstation for the program but files are stored back on SBS03). We also did this on the SBS08/VPN so location 2 users can get to files.

Users in location 2 in order to get this program must use remote desktop to access the VPN. Once on the VPN they enter their user name and password to get to their desktop on the domain. Here is where our problem lies and need to find a work around. The program allows only 1 user per computer to access database so when the agent/access point is installed on the VPN it is for the entire computer specific to each user. What happens is user 1 logs in no problem but when user 2 logs in the program opens its start screen but crashes after 45-60 seconds. Is there a fix for this that we are not thinking about? I talked to a cloud software hosting company and they said the only way they can get it to work is designate a different server for each user since multiple users can not be logged into 1 server at same time and access files.

Is there possibly a way to share a folder in location 1 as a drive on computers in location 2? If so this would solve our problem as each user would have the agent/access point installed on their individual computer and not be sharing a piece of the VPN pie.